# Buildbuf buf breaking protoc-gen-validate

Tags: protocol-buffers, buf

I'm trying to detect breaking protobuf changes in our CI workflow but I'm running into an issue with our use of `protoc-gen-validate`.

```
$ npx buf breaking . --against '.git#branch=main'
command/command.proto:5:8:validate/validate.proto: does not exist
```

This is my `buf.yaml`:

```
version: v1
breaking:
    use:
        - WIRE
lint:
    use:
        - DEFAULT
deps:
    - buf.build/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate
```

How can I convince `buf breaking` to use/install `protoc-gen-validate` or at least ignore the import.

Thanks